# Merging Dataframes and getting extra rows. (Python/Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have two data frames. One with employee IDs. And one with employee IDs and a Boolean value that indicates if they were given a raise when they asked (they can ask multiple times).

| ID |
| --- |
| 5 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
| 22 |

| ID | Raise |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | True |
| 5 | False |
| 5 | True |
| 8 | True |
| 9 | True |
| 22 | False |

How can I create a dataframe that merges employee IDs and whether they were given a raise (regardless of how many times they asked)? Like the following.

| ID | Raise |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | True |
| 8 | True |
| 9 | True |
| 22 | False |

Whenever I try to merge normally, extra rows are created due to multiple of the same ID.

Comment: you need to aggregate your second dataframe on the `ID` so that you have only the values you want to display. So if I understand correctly, you need a groupby, not a merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be what you're looking for

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'ID': [5, 5, 5, 8, 9, 22], 'Raise': [True, False, True, True, True, False]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   ID  Raise
0   5   True
1   5  False
2   5   True
3   8   True
4   9   True
5  22  False

In [4]: df.groupby('ID')['Raise'].any().reset_index()
Out[4]:
   ID  Raise
0   5   True
1   8   True
2   9   True
3  22  False
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Paul H said, you need an aggregation on the second dataframe

`df2.groupby("ID")["Raise"].any()`

Then you can merge with the first one using `ID`.